# Is there any OpenStack server validator tool?

Tags: client, webserver, validation, openstack

I'm building a webserver for OpenStack as part of my thesis at a data storage company for their data storage service. I need a tool that validates the server responses according to the OpenStack specifications and I also need a tool that can stress-test my webserver according to OpenStack specification. I've searched in google, but couldn't really find any such tools. Do you know about any such tools which would help me in my purpose. The specification that I'm following is found in this link http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide-20120601.pdf. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've changed the question, could you understand this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator as you describe doesn't exist as a tool or separate utility. You can, however, run all of OpenStack in a relatively small virtual machine (1GB VM) using the devstack script (see http://devstack.org).

Its not fast, but it is definitively, the APIs you are wanting to work against. Snapshot that VM, and you can recreate it at need to test your web service at your liesure. Its not something i would recommend for performance testing, but then Im not sure what your writing or wanting to test to be able to make any reasonable recommendations there.

Comment: Hi, I changed the question, may be you will have a more clear idea now about what I want. Thanks for your answer, but that's not quite what I want. I'm not doing a OpenStack installation. All I'm doing is making a webserver which will respond to client requests if the client is sending headers and bodies according to OpenStack specifications. But what I want to do is to make sure that what I'm doing is accurate, that's why I need a validator.

Comment: updated the answer - basically - try out devstack for this need. It's heavier than you probably hoped for, but will do exactly what you need.

Comment: And there is an API testing tool for devstack also. I work on this tool. http://vrest.io/i/demo/OS